# How to backup MongoDB in a setup with multiple Docker containers?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I have an application which is split into multiple Docker containers:

- Container 1 contains a MongoDB database
- Container 2 contains a python script which performs some operations on a daily basis and stores the results in the MongoDB of Container 1 using pymongo.

Previously to using Docker, i.e., having the MongoDB and the python app on the same machine, I could use mongoexport right after the daily scripts finished to backup my database. However, in the Docker setup, I can not use mongoexport in Container 2 because MongoDB is not installed, i.e., the command is unknown.

From my point of view, the only option would be using a cronjob in Container 1 running a script which performs the backup on a preset time.
However, I would prefer a solution in which Container 2 triggers the backup since the runtime of the daily scripts can vary considerably.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: How do you trigger the daily scripts in container 2?

Comment: Since it is a python script, I use schedule, a small python library which I consider to be more user friendly than a Cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

You can download mongodb binaries on docker 2 form [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center). That way you can get rid of `the command is unknown`

You can export mongodb collection from mongodb running on `container 1` using `mongoexport` or take dump using `mongodump` from `container 2` using `--host` and `--port` options.

Note: `mongoexport` does not export indexes from collection.